# Dynamic column value with group by (sql server and Linq)

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

i have a table `Plan` with following sample data
[image]
i want to aggregate the result by PlanMonth and for PlanStatus i want that if any of its (in a group) values is `Drafted` i get drafted in the result and `Under Approval` otherwise. i have done it using following query

```
select PlanMonth, case when Flag=1 then 'Drafted' else 'Under Approval' end as PlanStatus
from 
(select p.PlanMonth, Max(CASE WHEN p.PlanStatus = 'Drafted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Flag 
from Plans p 
group by p.PlanMonth
  ) inquery
```

i have consulted [this blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/07/11/1744.aspx). Is there something wrong with it? Moreover, if someone can help me translate it to linq i will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

The query you have will work.

With the sample data you have provided it can be simplified a bit.

```
select p.PlanMonth,
       min(p.PlanStatus) as PlanStatus
from Plans as p
group by p.PlanMonth
```

This will not work if you have values in `PlanStatus` that is alphabetically sorted before `Drafted`.

Comment: @Mikiael i need textual representation like `Drafted` and `under approval` ur query will give me 1 or 0

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid Not if your sample data is what you say it is.

Answer (score 0):

Following Linq query worked for me

```
 return (from p in db.mktDrVisitPlans                        

                    group p by p.PlanMonth into grop
                    select
                    new VMVisitPlan
                    {
                        PlanMonth = grop.Key
                        PlanStatus = grop.Any(x=>x.p.PlanStatus == "Drafted")?"Hold":"Under Approval",

                    }).ToList();
```